# Reading XML database according to schema

Tags: xml, database, vb.net, xsd, relational

I am having a hard time trying to work with a DataSet, specifically when trying to validate XML data against an schema file.

I am programming with Visual Studio 2008, the XSD is created with it.

I rely on Altova XMLSpy in order to make offline validations, and the troubling comes out when Altova has no complaints when validating data against the schema, yet my VB.NET code is raising an exception.

The code simple reads the XSD schema file, then the XML data file:

```
Dim tmpDataSet As New DataSet
(...)
tmpDataSet.ReadXmlSchema(xsdtreamreader)
tmpDataSet.ReadXml(xmltreamreader)
```

When executing last line, the following exception occurs:

```
Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.
```

Comment: You're much more likely to get good responses to questions on Stack Overflow if the information in your question allows others to reproduce the problem.  Can you replicate your problem with a twenty-line schema document and a ten-line document?  See if you can, and include that material in your question.  If you can't, that may be a clue, too.  There is good advice on asking effective questions in the [SO help files](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and in Eric Raymond and Rick Moen's essay [How to ask questions the smart way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Answer (score 0):

You are right, C. M. Sperberg-McQueen, so let's put it simple.

I tested with a minimal schema file containing only two tables and a relation one-to-many between them (schema file copied below).

Then I inserted 2 records only in the parent table (data file copied below).

As expected, XMLSpy validates the data against the schema without problem.

Then how does .NET deal with it?

If you first read data then the schema file, everything works well:

```
tmpDataSet.ReadXmlSchema(_dataSchema)
tmpDataSet.ReadXml(_dataXml)
```

However, if you do it in reverse:

```
tmpDataSet.ReadXml(_dataXml)
tmpDataSet.ReadXmlSchema(_dataSchema)
```

the following exception arises:

```
Invalid 'Key' node inside constraint named: FK_MonitoringPoint_ChannelProfile.
```

So first lesson is you have to read the schema first, as I have read somewhere.

This will however not work in some real situation, with a more complicated schema and more data, as I stated in my first post, with only the following generic excepcion message:

```
Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.
```

In this situation, I'm unable to know why validation failed and why this differs from XMLSpy saying the file is valid.

Comment: I am unable to paste the XSD and XML contents and I don't know how to attach files...